# Reg exp wanted for replacing all non-alphanumeric chars with underscores

Tags: php, regex

I want a reg exp for generating SEO-friendly URLs, so things like:

```
My product name
```

becomes

`My_product_name`

```
This is a long,long,long!!sentence
```

becomes

```
This_is_a_long_long_long_sentence
```

Basically so all non-alphanumeric chars are removed and replaced with underscores.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '_', $sentence)`

Basically it looks for any sequence of non-alphanumeric characters and replaces it with a single '_'. This way, you also avoid having two consecutive _'s in your output.

If it's for URLs, you probably also want them to be lower-case only:

`preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/', '_', strtolower($sentence))`

Comment: If this replaces all occurrences of non-alphanumeric characters in $sentence is the + really needed?

Comment: If you remove the +, each occurance of a single non-alphanumeric character will be replaced by `_`. If your original string has two non-alphanumeric characters following each other, the resulting string will contain `__` which you probably don't want

Comment: Note that with this answer you may still have a `_` at the beginning and/or end of the string, so you're best to add the `$a = trim($a, '_');` also (+1 to stereofrog for that one)

Comment: There's one caveat here.  This only works on ASCII text.  For any word characters not representable by A-Z you probably want to still keep them but URL encode them.

Comment: Any examples of non ascii characters?

Comment: Leaving __ or even ___ untouched is exactly what I want. Thanks for mentioning that about + sign.

Answer (score 5):

```
 $a = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/", "_", $str);
```

or /\W+/ if you want to keep everything that is considered a "letter" in the current locale

after replacement it may be also neccessary to stip leading and trailing underscores

```
 $a = trim($a, '_');
```

Comment: Or use a unicode property such as \pL or \pN:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = preg_replace("`[^a-z\d]+`i", "_", $str);
```